# Laravel / Livewire - Date is off by one day

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-livewire

I'm not sure where this comes from but the default `HTML` datepicker is off by one day while using `laravel` and `livewire`.

This code:

```
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label for="birthdate" value="{{ __('Geburtsdatum') }}" />
    <x-jet-input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="date" class="mt-1 mb-6 w-full" wire:model="details.birthdate"/>
    <x-jet-input-error for="details.birthdate" class="mt-2" />

    {{$details->birthdate}}
</div>
```

ends up like this:

[image: datepicker off by one day]

I use this code to ensure that the birthday format in my model is the way that I expect it to be:

```
protected $casts = [
    'birthdate' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];
```

The same with the validation rules in my livewire component:

```
protected $rules = [
    'details.birthdate' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];
```

Also i use the `date` format in my `mysql` database.

And the value seems to be right as `2021-02-02` but inserting this using `wire:model` it ends up as `2021-02-01`.

**Does someone know where this behaviour comes from?**

Comment: Time zone issue, perhaps? 2021-02-02 at midnight CET is still 2021-02-01 in UTC..

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Mark Reed. The `timezone`-attribute in my config/app.php file is set to 'Europe/Berlin'. As I'm from germany this should be right. Or is there another config setting that I'm missing?

Comment: What's the timezone for the MySQL server?

Comment: It's an eu-central-1 instance from `aws`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we found what was causing the problem. We had a protected variable in our `model`:

```
protected $dates = ['birthdate'];
```

After deleting this, if finally worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Ideally have to set application timezone to UTC and just format the timezone on display.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32795117)